# .NET 5 Указание директивы в разных файлах

Tags: c#, .net-5

Изначально, я шёл сюда за ответом на вопрос ".NET 5 не видит SqlConnection". Но, пока писал вопрос пришёл к ответу.
Теперь по порядку. В текущем .NETframework WPF приложении есть директива

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Далее, используется класс `SQLConnection` для создания строки подключения и сама строка, как вы уже поняли используется во время различных операции с БД.

Далее, я начал ленивую миграцию на .NET 5. Так же создал WPF приложение, так же указал вышеупомянутую директиву, создал класс `SQLConnection` и строку подключения. Студия сразу же выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error CS1069 the "SqlConnectionStringBuilder" type name Could not be found in the "System.Data.SqlClient"namespace. This type was sent to the build "System. Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Try adding a link to this build.
```

Я какое то время не мог понять, в чём дело? Ведь в справке Майкрософт прямо указано, что данный класс поддерживается в .NET 5. ЧЯДНТ?
**ОТВЕТ** на **ЧЯДНТ**:
Ответ хранится тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-dotnet-core#create-a-new-net-core-project
пункт 2.

> В текстовом редакторе откройте sqltest.csproj и вставьте следующий
> XML-код между тегами . Этот XML-код добавляет
> System.Data.SqlClient как зависимость.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

и всё работает.

### Мой текущий вопрос:

Почему ниже по коду используется директива `using System.Data.SqlClient;` которая не работает до тех пор, пока я не добавлю этот же XML-код в .csproj и почему ничего такого делать ненужно в .Netframework? Я указываю директиву и вперёд.

---

Comment: Потому что вы не смотрите какие ссылки у вас в проекте по умолчанию при использовании `.NET Framework`. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/gg145028(v=vs.110) по ссылке как раз в данной библиотеке и содержится интересующий вас класс, а сама библиотека по умолчанию подключена.

Comment: Потому что в современном .net не подключены по умолчанию библиотеки. Вы должны их подключать через nuget

Comment: @AzizUmarov интересная движуха началась у Майкрософт) Обычно, они всегда старались сделать так, чтобы всё было одним нажатием кнопки, а теперь нужно самим.

Comment: Это из-за .net core и линукс. В основном конечно же линукс

Comment: @AzizUmarov хотел сказать, что это какой-то Linux-way.

Comment: Если почитать Android это линух, и нужно уменьшать бандл и пихать только то что необходимо то это линух вай

Comment: Без плясок по умолчанию доступны только кросс-платформенные компоненты, остальное либо еще не прикрутили, либо уехало в NuGet.

Comment: Раньше был большой, даже огромный, Framework, в состав которого входят тысячи классов, в том числе для работы с SqlServer. Теперь имеется только небольшое ядро, а всё прочее следует устанавливать дополнительно в виде пакетов. Раньше пользователю при установке приложения .NET приходилось скачивать и устанавливать этот большой фреймворке, теперь для .NET Core / 5 достаточно небольшого ядра и минимума библиотек. Как-то так.

Comment: Здесь нет никакого Linux-way. При работе в Visual Studio пакет также можно подключить нажатием кнопки, инструкция по ручному редактированию файла проекта - это для тех, кто работает в блокноте.

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать, почему  System.Data.SqlClient подключается из netcore Они не переписали его в net5?

Answer (score 1):

Как подсказал @AzizUmarov суть оказалась в том, что сейчас Майкрософт для ускорения процесса создания нового проекта по-умолчанию отключает почти всё. Поэтому, многие зависимости нужно подключать самостоятельно. Либо через VStudio в разделе с NuGet (или с помощью команды), либо добавлять в файл `sqltest.csproj` необходимые зависимости.